# Symfony - Application Layout Directory

Tags: php, layout, symfony1

I would like administrators to be able to upload new layouts for the frontend application in my Symfony app. Is there a way to either change the layout directory for a specific app or allow uploads to that directory?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's a method for setting the layout directory view-specifically on the fly:

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfView#method_setdecoratordirectory

It takes a path so your guys would upload into the uploads/ directory and your app would grab them from there.

The only implementation example I could find was:

http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/77051/

Hope that at least points you in the right direction.